# Rolling 3 month sum in SQL

Tags: sql

I would like to have rolling 3 month sum as in the example from Excel below. This window should roll over month and should always begin with the first day of month and sum amount from another column as in the last row in the example. Is it possible to do it with window functions? I know how to do it daily with window function, but i have no idea how i can get the data like this using SQL.
In my dataset i have only columns with "date", "notional_amount".

[image: Excel example]

This is how my example dataset look like(just few rows)
[image: dataset]

Comment: It would be helpful to include an example data set. I'm not entirely sure what you are saying it looks like. You have Date and Amount, and you want the output to have Month and Rolling Sum of Amount? And you want each row to be the sum of "6 months ago" until "3 months ago"?

Comment: I added example dataset. I would like to receive column grouped by reg cap requirement, which are dates 1.01.2021, 1.02.2021 etc. and from this date should be 6 months back to calculate 3 month sum based on dataset.

Comment: Okay now I see. I think this is basically a duplicate, though, of questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551008/sql-server-rolling-12-months-sum-with-date-gaps) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41780171/rolling-sum-previous-3-months-sql-server)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sql server rolling 12 months sum with date gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551008/sql-server-rolling-12-months-sum-with-date-gaps)

Comment: Not exactly the same but indicates good direction i think. I have just one question, how can I generate first days of all months in 2021 just using CTE?

Comment: The CTE in my linked question basically does it. You can simplify a little I think with [this sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b4c1c1/1)

Comment: Thank you very much for help Dylan :) This is what i wanted